# Jersey 2 gzip compression not have Content-Encoding header in response

Tags: java, rest, gzip, jersey-2.0

I have read this: [compress-responses-in-jersey](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-compress-responses-in-java-rest-api-with-gzip-and-jersey/) and have Jersey 2 config:

```
    @ApplicationPath("/jaxrs/")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public AppConfig() {
        super(AdvertisementResource.class, MultiPartFeature.class);
        packages("jaxrs");
        EncodingFilter.enableFor(this, GZipEncoder.class, DeflateEncoder.class);
    }
}
```

I have header Request:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/jaxrs/admin-adblock
Accept:application/json
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Basic c21h... 
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
```

But header response are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Jetty(9.2.2.v20140723)
```

Header in response `Content-Encoding:gzip` is missing only `Vary: Accept-Encoding` is appear if I have:

```
EncodingFilter.enableFor(this, GZipEncoder.class, DeflateEncoder.class);
```

If I remove compression and comment EncodingFilter row response header are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.2.2.v20140723)
```

or this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 369
Server: Jetty(9.2.2.v20140723)
```

I`m testing with [Intellij Rest Client Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/rest-client-tool-window.html) and I`m not sure if I receive compressed response from server?

I have download jersey sources and set breakpoint [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/f874edcd60a083b84ba3d26d715c2590c7a1a7e7/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/EncodingFilter.java#L196) and debug rest service web application with Intellij it appears that CONTENT_ENCODING gzip is added here:

```
response.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, contentEncoding);
```

but its missing in response header from Intellij Rest Client tool..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have download SoapUI and test the same Rest requests response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 204
Server: Jetty(9.2.2.v20140723)
```

The Intellij Rest Client Tool is hiding response headers Content-Encoding and Content-Length..
I have open new [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145222)